# SQL query for counting number of records

Tags: sql, reporting-services

HI I'm showing records in report state wise data example is below

```
NAME     STATE
BOB      NSW
PETER    ACT
SAM      NSW
BOY      VIC
```

And I need to count per record per state wise to show in SSRS report.I am trying with row number and partition by. But it is showing 1,2,3,4. That's what it should be. Any other recommendation And expected result should be for NSW =2
VIC=1 and ACT =1

Comment: Expected results please.

Comment: What are you counting exactly? There are 4 rows, 1 for each listed state or 1 for each listed name. row_number() isn't actually a count, it increments by 1 for each row within a partition, so the last row will equal the equivalent count, but only on that row. Could you clarify what the expected result should be? The question is very vague.

Comment: I am expecting result as below COUNT for NSW 2,For ACT 1 and for VIC 1 .Like as many time NSW it count as 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([NAME] varchar(5), [STATE] varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO T
    ([NAME], [STATE])
VALUES
    ('BOB', 'NSW'),
    ('PETER', 'ACT'),
    ('SAM', 'NSW'),
    ('BOY', 'VIC')
;

SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(State) FROM T WHERE State = T1.State) StateCount
FROM T T1;
```

**Returns:**

```
+-------+-------+------------+
| NAME  | STATE | StateCount |
+-------+-------+------------+
| BOB   | NSW   |          2 |
| PETER | ACT   |          1 |
| SAM   | NSW   |          2 |
| BOY   | VIC   |          1 |
+-------+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT state, count(name) AS count
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY state
ORDER BY state
```

?